# Getting "AuthorizationPermissionMismatch" on a public container

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We use the NodeJS ***@azure/storage-blob*** SDK to access the **storage container/blobs** in our organization. We have a system developed wherein the users can access the private containers by logging in into our servers and their accounts being added via our admin to certain IAM roles (*Either giving them read/write/delete access to the blobs*).

Now, we want to enable some new users to access to **public container/blobs** by default. We have made a container public and the public links to these **storage containers/blobs** are accessible by a URL but when trying to access them via the NodeJS API we get the "**AuthorizationPermissionMismatch**" error.

The code we use is below:

```
function getBlobDirectories(result) {
   console.log(result);
}

function errorinlisting(err) {
   console.log(err);
}

const containerClient = global.getBlobService(this.storageAccount,req.user).getContainerClient(this.containerName);
let blobDirIterator = containerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy('/');
blobDirIterator.next().then(getBlobDirectories).catch(errorinlisting);
```

The function getBlobService looks like this:

```
exports.getBlobService = (storageAcc, user)=> {
    const account = storageAcc;
    const accountKey = storageaccountkeys[storageAcc]

    let blobServiceClient;

    const simpleTokenCredential = new SimpleTokenCredential(user.azureToken);
        blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
            `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
            simpleTokenCredential
        );
    return blobServiceClient;
}
```

Calling listBlobsByHierarchy, end up in error which ends up calling the `errorinlisting` function above with "**AuthorizationPermissionMismatch**" error..

What could be the issue? Is this a bug in the NodeJS API?

Any help would be invaluable.

Comment: What is `req.user` in `global.getBlobService(this.storageAccount,req.user)`?

Comment: @GauravMantri I have updated the answer now. azureToken is the access token that I get when I log in using the Microsoft link.

Comment: Thanks. Please see if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52769758/azure-blob-storage-authorization-permission-mismatch-error-for-get-request-wit.

Comment: No it does not.

Answer (score 0):

If your container is public accessible you might want to try create an instance of `ContainerClient` without a credential:

```js
const { ContainerClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob")

const url = "<url to container with anonymous access>";
const containerClient = new ContainerClient(url);

async function main() {
    for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
        console.log(blob.name);
    }
}

main().catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
})
```