# Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: containers.Client#ListBlobs:

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

```
Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: containers.Client#ListBlobs: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailure" Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation.\nRequestId:XXX"
```

I am using azure storage as Terraform backend. It was working fine. I removed a private endpoint for the storage from configuration and did terraform apply. It starts giving me this error. Is there need of Private endpoint for storing Terraform state in Azure storage? Also not sure why got above error. I am unable to do terraform init with this error.

Comment: Did you execute `az login` before any terraform command? You must validate that you have access to the Storage Account via AZ CLI

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, Terraform was working locally and saving the state file in the storage container but failed with a similar error in AzureDevop using the `TerraformTaskV3@3` task:

```
│ Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: containers.Client#ListBlobs: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationPermissionMismatch"
```

So I assigned the `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role to the service principal I used to connect DevOps to the azure container.

Reference: [Azure Blob Storage "Authorization Permission Mismatch" error for get request with AD token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52769758/azure-blob-storage-authorization-permission-mismatch-error-for-get-request-wit)

Answer (score 2):

I tried in my environment and got below results:

**Main**

```
provider  "azurerm" {
features{
resource_group {
prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources  =  false
}
}
}
provider  "azuread" {
}

data  "azurerm_resource_group"  "example" {
name  =  "< Resource group name >"
}
data  "azurerm_storage_account"  "example" {
name  =  "venkat123"
resource_group_name  =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
terraform {
backend  "azurerm" {
resource_group_name  =  "< Resource group name >"
storage_account_name  =  "venkat123"
container_name  =  "test"
key  =  "terraform.tfstate"
}
}
```

Before running the code make sure you have make sure you were logged in with your credentials:

```bash
az login --tenant <tenant ID>
az account set --subscription <subscription ID>
```

**Console:**
[image]

Yes, you can access the storage account without private endpoints.

**Portal:**

[image]

> ```
> containers.Client#ListBlobs: Failure responding to request:
> StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an
> error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailure" Message="This request is
> not authorized to perform this operation.\nRequestId:XXX"
> ```

The above error shows that doesn't has proper permission to authorize the azure blob storage.

Check the firewall settings whether, In networking

- If you are access in public enable the select all network
- If you enabled selected networks add the virtual networks. and add your add your client iP address and also enable **`"Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account"`** allows you to access storage account.

[image]

- Make sure that you have the necessary permission, such as the **`Contributor`** and **`User Access Administrator roles`** and the **`Storage Blob Data Owner role.`**

**Reference:**
[Creating Azure Storage Containers in a storage account with network rules, with Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022815/creating-azure-storage-containers-in-a-storage-account-with-network-rules-with) by Ansuman Bal

Comment: Getting this error after applying some Front Door Profile changes to our Storage account (added front door endpoint, route, WAF). I hadn't configured the WAF policy correctly, so after the pipeline successfully applied the WAF policy changes, the storage account was locked down. I resolved this by manually deleting the Front Door profile in the Azure Portal

Answer (score 0):

Given that I am using Azure storage to store the remote backend, and my state is in a different subscription than the resources managed by terraform, I often bump into this. It can be solved by:

1. Generating an SAS token to grant access to the container where I was storing the state. I used this command:

> ```
>   az storage container generate-sas \
>       --account-name $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME \
>       --account-key $ACCOUNT_KEY \
>       --name $CONTAINER_NAME \
>       --permissions "rwl" \
>       --expiry $EXPIRY_TIME \
>       --output tsv
> ```

2. Export `ARM_SAS_TOKEN` with the generated token, as an environment variable

Answer (score 0):

more than likely it might be as simple as a typo in what you called the container or how you made the variable. that was my issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34977118)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this issue, I experienced the same thing using the `ubuntu WSL` terminal on Windows 11. AZ login was working fine, I was even able to show the blob details successfully using the Azure CLI but for some reason, I couldn't do `terraform init/plan` and I also couldn't list storage accounts using the `Azure Storage Explorer` even after authenticating successfully. So, I decided to reboot my laptop, and voila, `terraform init, plan`, and Storage Explorer working again! So, seems like something went awry with how tools use the underlying authenticated/established azure user session.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing @ccoutinho's answer (but apparently I don't login often enough to reply directly), using a Shared access token with RWL then exporting to env var ARM_SAS_TOKEN worked for me to get past the same error.

Instead of generating the token programmatically (to avoid fighting with timestamps) I used the Az UI feature under Settings > Shared access tokens on the container. Need to remember to tune the permissions - mine did not work when I first did this as I needed the write perm in order to update state and it defaults to read-only.