# Error 403 Terraform Init in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a project on Azure Devops or I tried to run terraform to deploy resources on another Azure tenant (different from my Azure Devops tenant) But when I run terraform init I receive the following error:

```
Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: containers.Client#ListBlobs: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest returned/azure: Service an error. Status=403 Code="AuthenticationFailed" Message="The server failed to authenticate the request. Ensure that the authorization header value is properly formed, including the signature.
```

Comment: HAve you set up the correct permissions for your credentials running terraform to have access to the other tenant?

Comment: I created the storage and account using a contributor access

Answer (score 0):

The above error occurs when the user or service principal you are trying to authenticate with has no **`Storage Blob Data Owner role`** or **`Storage Blob Data Contributor role`** role assigned at the storage account level in another tenant.

One alternative is to create a Service Principal in another tenant that has contributor role assigned at the Subscription or the Resource group level where you want to create the Storage account or deploy resources using terraform.

Create a Service Principal in Azure AD with client secret in your another tenant with Contributor role and Storage Blob Data contributor role assigned at the subscription or storage account level by referring to this [Document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) and use it for authentication to create or manage storage account like below:-

**My main.tf file:-**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.8.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "xxxxx97cb2a7"
  tenant_id = "xxxx4-99ed-af9038592395"
  client_id = "xxxxb838-6d26a31435cb"
  client_secret = "xxxxxfEGZ3ZgxRt8313-CS0ifbLE"
  features {}  
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "appgrp" {
  name     = "silicon-resrcgrp"
  location = "North Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "appstore566565637" {
  name                     = "siliconstrg543"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.appgrp.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.appgrp.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind = "StorageV2"
}
```

**Devops Release pipeline:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]

**Reference:-**

[azure - Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: containers.Client#ListBlobs: - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74431658/error-failed-to-get-existing-workspaces-containers-clientlistblobs)