# Azure devops - Lock azure resource for users but enable it for azure devops (release, pipeline)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, devops

We are currently using terraform to create azure resources and this will be no different in the future.
My question to you is, is there a possibility to lock resource group modification and deletion for users, but allow it for Azure Devops release pipeline (which run terraform)?
We also run the tests in local environment and we don't want someone to accidentally overwrite the existing UAT/PROD environment.

Could we probably create some ACLs or disable user permission on the resource and only allow the Devops app to use it? But that's not the best solution either, because sometimes you have to manually make changes on a rescource. (scale, restart, NSG etc...)

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check the answer below? May I know if it can address your concern？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a Read only lock at the resource group level and you want to Deploy a Resource in the same Resource Group, The Lock won't allow the DevOps pipeline and service principal to deploy the resource as in Read-Only Lock you cannot modify or update resource, Its same as Reader role at the resource level. You can assign a service principal at the resource group or resource level to modify the resource by removing the Lock temporarily and assigning it back after the  respective update operation. Also, One more alternative is to keep one User or Service principal with Contributor role and one User or service principal with Reader role without any Locks. You can utilize the User with Contributor role to modify and update the resource and Use another User with Reader role to Read the resource by allowing Least privileged access.

***I tried deploying a Storage account via Azure DevOps Release pipeline with Read-Only-Lock at Resource Group level, And the Lock restricted the Deployment. Refer below:-***

[image]

[image]

***I removed the Read-Only-Lock and applied CannotDelete Lock and The Deployment was successful. Here, I can modify the resource and perform operational tasks but cannot delete it.***

[image]

[image]

[image]

If there's a Cannot Delete Lock, You can modify and update the resource but cannot delete here. Here' Scaling of VM or creating and updating Blob container in storage account will work.

My Release pipeline Tasks **[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76764423/error-403-terraform-init-in-azure-devops/76770351#).**

Reference in understanding Locks **[here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/management/lock-resources.md).**