# AuthorizationPermissionMismatch when copy blobs across different storage accounts

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-python-sdk

I am using below code to copy blob across different storage accounts, but it fails with the below error

```
src_blob = '{0}/{1}?{2}'.format('source_url',b_name,'sp=rw&st=2022-11-17T20:44:03Z&se=2022-12-31T04:44:03Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=c&sig=ZXRe2FptVF5ArRM%2BKDAkLboCN%2FfaD9Mx38yZGWhnps0%3D')

            destination_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("destination_connection_string")//The connection string has sas token which has sr=c
            copied_blob = destination_client.get_blob_client('standardfeed', b_name)
            copied_blob.start_copy_from_url(src_blob)
```

ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

Any thing missing or did I copy the wrong SAS token?

Comment: @Venkatesan I am already doing it using format

src_blob = '{0}/{1}?{2}'.format('source_url',b_name,'sp=rw&st=2022-11-17T20:44:03Z&se=2022-12-31T04:44:03Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=c&sig=ZXRe2FptVF5ArRM%2BKDAkLboCN%2FfaD9Mx38yZGWhnps0%3D')

Comment: In your source_url have you mentioned container name?

Comment: Can you share what destination connection string looks like?

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and successfully copied blob from one storage account to another storage account.**

**Code:**

```
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient

b_name="sample1.pdf"

src_blob = '{0}/{1}?{2}'.format('https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test',b_name,'sp=r&st=2022-11-18T07:46:10Z&se=2022-11-18T15:46:10Z&spr=https&sv=<SAS token >)

destination_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("<connection string>")

copied_blob = destination_client.get_blob_client('test1', b_name)

copied_blob.start_copy_from_url(src_blob)
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

Make sure you has necessary permission for authentication purpose you need to assign roles in your storage account.

- **Storage Blob Data Contributor**
- **Storage Blob Data Reader**

**Portal:**

[image]

**Update:**

You can get the connection string through portal:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Azure Blob Storage "Authorization Permission Mismatch" error for get request with AD token - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52769758/azure-blob-storage-authorization-permission-mismatch-error-for-get-request-wit)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Let me try and then let you know.